# Is mysql.timezone_name's Time_zone_id "static"?

Tags: mysql, timezone

I'm building a application that needs to store Timezones.
Rather than building my own table of timezones would it be copacetic to use mysql's already there table (mysql.time_zone_names)?

If I use a Time_zone_id of '94' and mysql updates its timezone tables, will 94 still be America/Chicago?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL loads its timezone tables from your OS's /usr/share/lib/zoneinfo when you run `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql`. Then it keeps the data in the `mysql` database.

So the entries are only as stable as that file. If the OS adds or removes time zones in zoneinfo, and you reinstall your MySQL instance and run `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` again to load the changed time zones, then the numeric time_zone_id values in MySQL could change.

I would recommend using the timezone name, not the numeric id.

Comment: "MySQL loads its timzone tables from your OS"... when available.. otherwise the data is downloadable - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html    re using the timezone name.  If I go that route I wouldn't even need a table of timezone names.   seems to go against the normalization principal

Comment: I have edited the above to clarify that the OS zoneinfo is read only at installation time. It keeps the data in MySQL after that. How does this go against normalization? Which normal form are you proposing that it conflicts with?

Comment: looks like I was misusing the term "normalization"..   I guess I'd prefer enum or lookup-table vs multiple duplicated strings.   Data integrity (prevent invalid values) and storage optimization.  Thanks

Comment: Lookup tables also mean you have to join when querying, which is not free.  There are always tradeoffs.  In general, it's pretty common to see string foreign keys like time zone identifiers kept as strings.  Similarly, consider country codes, etc.  Would you really want the overhead for something like `'US'`?  It's no different than with `'America/Los_Angeles'`.